# Bootstrap switch not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a Bootstrap switch, by default it's set to off but when I click on it does not change?

I grabbed the codes of this site where it works fine: http://www.bootply.com/92189
Maybe I'm missing something? I'm really not sure.

***EDIT:*** 
Why does it not work with the javascript in the script tags, but instead it works in JSFiddles javascript container?
http://prntscr.com/47xuqk
http://prntscr.com/47xuy6

thanks

JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/udKj5/)

Javascript:

```
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');  

    if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-info').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-info');
    }

    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');

});

$('form').submit(function(){
    alert($(this["options"]).val());
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<h4>Tiny</h4>
  <div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default">ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">OFF</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery, but not adding it to the fiddle. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/udKj5/2/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included jQuery, which is a required dependency for certain Bootstrap elements. You're also referencing the default global jQuery variable (`$`).

Add the jQuery framework and you should be good to go:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```